# Using If statement to hide/delete/remove field of a column codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, postgresql

I'm using codeigniter and postgresql

I'm getting troubled using IF statement in Views

What I want to do is that *if seq=3* I dont want to put this code.

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'TestController/change/'.$v->seq?>"> EDIT/ADD</a></td>
```

Sample Table

```
   seq   column1   column2
    1      null       null     EDIT/ADD
    2      null       null     EDIT/ADD
    3      null       null     EDIT/ADD
```

Result should be like this:

```
   seq   column1   column2
    1      null       null     EDIT/ADD
    2      null       null     EDIT/ADD
    3      null       null
```

The actual code for this in Views for Sample Table above

```
 <tbody>
    <?php   foreach ($value as $v){ ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $v->seq?></td>
          <td><?php echo $v->column1?></td>
          <td><?php echo $v->column2?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'ThesisController/change/'.$v->seq?>"> EDIT/ADD</a></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
 </tbody>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
<?php 
   $count = 0;
    foreach ($value as $v){      
    $count++;     
     ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $v->seq?></td>
          <td><?php echo $v->column1?></td>
          <td><?php echo $v->column2?></td>
          <td>
           <?php
            if($count!=3)
             {
           ?>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url().'ThesisController/change/'.$v->seq?>"> EDIT/ADD</a>
         <?php
          }
          else
           {
                  echo "&nbsp;";
           }
         ?>
         </td>
       </tr>
<?php       
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: My mistake, I deleted some. But it really did work. Tnx. If you dont mind, whats is &nbsp?

Comment: &nbsp; is empty space.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
<?php   foreach ($value as $v){ ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $v->seq?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->column1?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->column2?></td>
      <?php if ($v->seq == 3) { ?>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <?php } else { ?>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'ThesisController/change/'.$v->seq?>"> EDIT/ADD</a></td>
      <?php }?>
   </tr>
```

Comment: I see, so this could be another answer. Tnx too man. I'll try this too